# How to filter values in my generator expression

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, conditional-operator, generator-expression

My function below is calculating the depth of a nested dict.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def get_dict_depth(d, depth=0):
    if not isinstance(d, dict) or not d:
        return depth   
    return max(get_dict_depth(v, depth+1) if k != 'id' else depth for k, v in d.items())

foobar = {
        "key1" : "val1",
        "key2" : {
            "id" : "val2"
            },
        "new_d" : {
            "key" : "val",
            "key2" : {
                "id" : "blabla",
                "key" : {
                    "id" : "blabla",
                    }
                },
            }
        }

depth = get_dict_depth(foobar)
print("Depth %d" % depth)
```

I would like to modify it to not include keys that have the value `id` in the depth calculation. The program works if I use a ternary in the generator expression:

```
return max(get_dict_depth(v, depth+1) if k != 'id' else depth for k, v in d.items())
```

But I can't seem to make it work by filtering:

```
return max(get_dict_depth(v, depth+1) for k, v in d.items() if k != 'id')
```

Why isn't my filter working and how do I make it work?

Comment: it is not clear to me what you mean by *"I would like to modify it to not include keys that have the value `id` in the depth calculation"*. Can you elaborate? Maybe add an example?

Comment: What's the problem with using the ternary?

Comment: Can you convert your generator expressions to generator functions with the expressions *expanded* to a regular for loop, and include those in the post? It might illuminate the problem.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the current dict has a depth of 4. however, i don't want the last id to be included, so it should calculate to 3

Comment: @pault there's nothing wrong with the ternary. i'm just trying to understand how filters work and how to use them correctly

Comment: @wwii i'll try that out later

Comment: If you *unwind* your generator expressions, you can add some print functions in the resulting loop(s) to help you debug/understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Move the check to your `get_dict_depth` function:

```
def get_dict_depth(d, depth=0):
    if not isinstance(d, dict) or not d or 'id' in d:
        return depth
    return max(get_dict_depth(v, depth+1) for v in d.values())
```

This gives me the result:

```
Depth 2
```

Comment: but the depth is 3. it should be `foobar['new_d']['key2']['key']`. but besides that, i'm more interested in understanding how the filter works, or why it isn't working in my instance.